# how to include a jQuery file in php session file?

Tags: php, jquery, session

This is my php file where it creates a session for the user:-

```
<?php
    //starting the session
    session_start();

    //checking if session of user is set ot not
    if(isset($_SESSION['UID'])) {
        echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['UID'];

    }
    else {
        header("Location: ErrorPage.html");         
    }
?>
```

And this is my jQuery file:-

```
$(document).ready(
    function hiding() {           
        $("#links").hide();
    }
);
```

I want my "#links" to be hidden after a user logs in. How do I include the jQuery file in my if statement in php? I tried:-

```
include("jqueryFile.js");
require("jqueryFile.js");
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: why do you want to use javascript for something that can be done via CSS?

Comment: you can just assign CSS class if the user is logged in like "hidden" and in CSS write .hidden{ display: none;}. However even better approach would be probably to have two templates: one with menu for logged in user and the second one with menu for not logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require and include is for server side files, like php.

you should simply do something like

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryFile.js"></script>';
```

If you want to use the require/include commands you should store your javascript in a .php file

`require('jqueryFile.php')`;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryFile.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to output that file (ready to deploy into client)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
?>
   <script src='jqueryFile.js'></script>
   <script>hiding();</script>
<?php    
}
```

Comment: you can do something better than this